# question about transition matrix (Markov chains)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider two colorless balls in a box, in the n-step, i choose a random ball and throw a coin. if the choose ball is colorless and the coin falls head, then i paint red the ball; if the coin falls cross then i paint black the ball and in other case i keep the ball in the box. If the ball is colored, then i change the color of the ball no matter if the coin falls heads or cross. I have to do the transition matrix and i was thinking in $S={0,1,2}$ the state space and 0 means colorless, 1 is the red color and 2 is the black color and i was thinking in the transition matrix like this:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
but i do not know if the transition matrix is in coordenates $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ belongs of $S$, because i do not consider the fact of two balls in the box, just i consider the fact when i take the ball and i know the color from this ball.

Comment: I count six states.

Comment: There are two balls, both initially colorless, and then they can be painted red or black later? And the coin has no memory? Assuming you don't keep track of which ball is which later, that means that the number of distinct states is the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $c+r+b=2$ which is the number of positive integer solutions to $c+r+b=5$, of which there are 6.

Comment: (Cont.) If you don't like this combinatorial procedure, you can just enumerate the states: they are 2 colorless, 1 colorless 1 red, 1 colorless 1 black, 1 red 1 black, 2 red, 2 black. You need this much information to be embedded into the state for the chain to be Markov, because you need to know the probability that the ball you draw is colorless, red, or black.